# Avoid int overflow when doing a large multiplication

Tags: c++, modulo, integer-overflow

I'm training to participate in a programming contest, so I'm trying to get used to the common things in that kind of problems. I've been having problems with something in particular: int overflow due to insanely big numbers, there's this particular problem I would like to know how to solve: [Amelia and Rabbit Island](http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?pid=3801). This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

   unsigned long long int a,b,c;
   int t;

   int nweeks;

   std::cin >> t;

   int **lines = new int*[t];
   for (size_t i = 0;i<t;i++)
      lines[i] = new int[3];

   for(size_t i=0;i<t;i++)
      for(size_t j=0;j<3;j++)
         std::cin >> lines[i][j];  


   for (size_t i=0;i<t;i++){
      a = lines[i][1];
      b = lines[i][2];
      const unsigned int mod = 1000000;
      for (size_t j=0;j<lines[i][0] - 2;j++){

         if (j > 0){
            c = a;
            a = a * b % mod;
            b = c;

         }
         else {
            a = a * b;
         }
      }

      nweeks = (lines[i][0] * 3) - 2;

      std::cout << "At week " << nweeks << " we obtain " << a%mod << " new rabbits.\n";
   }


   for (size_t i=0;i<t;i++)
      delete[] lines[i];

   delete[] lines;
   return 0;
}
```

In the problem it says that the answer must be expressed in mod(1000000), this is supposed to avoid the overflow, but I just can't find the way to make it work, my solution works for normal values, but for example the specific case of the input:

> 1 1000 10 10

That is the maximum allowed input for a single case, the output I get is:

> At week 2998 we obtain 0 new rabbits.
>   Which is wrong, all because the int overflowing in multiplication.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Well, for some reason the evaluator system now accepts mi solution -.-, thanks anyway.

Comment: That problem has an unusual choice of using 1000000. Most of these problems are done 1000000007, which is a prime number that only requires 30 bits, which allows two numbers mod 1000000007  to be added without overflowing 32 bit unsigned integer, and multiply is typically done using 64 bit unsigned products before doing mod 1000000007.

Answer (score 1):

You have unfortunate selection of input.

If you add couple of lines to output `a` and `b` as the last lines of the `for` loop,

```
std::cout << "a: " << a << "\n";
std::cout << "b: " << b << "\n";
```

you can trace how the values of `a` and `b` change.

By using `1 10 10 10` as input, I get the following output:

```
a: 100
b: 10
a: 1000
b: 100
a: 100000
b: 1000
a: 0
b: 100000
a: 0
b: 0
a: 0
b: 0
a: 0
b: 0
a: 0
b: 0
At week 28 we obtain 0 new rabbits.
```

After that, `a` and `b` will continue to be zero. The answer is not incorrect. The output modulus 100000 is indeed zero.

By using `1 10 8 8` as input, I get the following output:

```
a: 64
b: 8
a: 512
b: 64
a: 32768
b: 512
a: 777216
b: 32768
a: 813888
b: 777216
a: 775808
b: 813888
a: 821504
b: 775808
a: 375232
b: 821504
At week 28 we obtain 375232 new rabbits.
```

which look more acceptable even though both sets of results are correct.